# how to sort product by price low to high and high to low in django with fillters

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-class-based-views

i want to sort product list by pricing low to high and high to low and render in template

my models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):

    categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='our_items')
    subcategories = models.ForeignKey(Subcategories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    can_buy = models.ForeignKey(For, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='for_wearing')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    contain_size = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='Bagh')
    first = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=False)
    second = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=False)
    third = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=True)
    fourth = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=True)
    fifth = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=True)
    rating = models.FloatField(blank=False,default='4.0')
    item_video = models.FileField(upload_to='item_vedio', blank=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, default='Black')
    material = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, default='Plastic' )
    return_policy = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='7Days Return Policy')
    stock = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, default='In Stock')
    price = models.FloatField(blank=False,)
    actual_price = models.FloatField(blank=False)
    type = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=100, default='washable')
    about = models.CharField(blank=False,max_length=100, default='Lusturous')
    offer = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True)
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,editable=False)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Subcategories(models.Model):
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='our_categories')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,editable=False)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

here is my views.py

```
class Product(View):
    def get(self, request, subcategory_id):
        subcategory = get_object_or_404(Subcategories, pk=subcategory_id)
        products = subcategory.products.all()
        category_list = Categories.objects.all()
        print(products)
        return render (request, 'products.html',{"subcategory_list" : products, 'category_list': category_list })
```

my html

```
<div class="col-10">
            <ul>
              <li class="filters"><strong>Sort By :</strong></li>
              <li class="filters"><a class="filter_by" href="">Popularity</a></li>
              <li class="filters"><a class="filter_by" href="">Price:--low to high</a></li>
              <li class="filters"><a class="filter_by" href="">Price:-- high to low</a></li>
              <li class="filters"><a class="filter_by" href="">Newest First</a></li>
              <li class="filters"><a class="filter_by" href="">Discount</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <section class="col-10">
          {% for products in subcategory_list %}
          <a class="products" href="{% url 'products:detail' item_id=products.id %}">
          <div class="card col-4" style="width: 18rem; height:420px">
              <img class="img" src="{{ products.first.url }}" alt="" height="300px" width="100%" onmouseover="this.src='{{ products.second.url }}'"
              onmouseout="this.src='{{ products.first.url }}'" >
              <div class="detail">
              <h4 class="price">{{ products.price|currency}}</h4>
              <h5>{{products.name}} <br> <span class="brand">{{ products.brand_name}}</span> <span class="btn btn-success buton">✔Authentic</span> </h5>
              <p class="rate">Rate: {{products.rating}}<i class="fas fa-star"></i></p>
              <h6>Size:<span> {{products.contain_size}}</span> </h6>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
            {% endfor %} 
          </div>  
        </section>
```

as you can see i created a div and in that i put sorting so what i want when a user click on that link it render the product list in that order but right i have no idea how to that i saw some document but that doesn't seem the best way to achieve that any idea which is the best way to achieve that
thank you for your time

Comment: What is `subcategory.products.all()` ? please update your question with Subcategory model, then I can tell the exact query to use.

Comment: @Prakhar added subcategory

Comment: What actually `subcategory.products` provides, there is no product field there !

Comment: products is related name in foreign key with linked subctegories

Comment: ahh ! got it  my bad :D

Comment: Try out the answer and let me know, in case of doubt/error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your html

```
<li class="filters"><a class="filter_by" href="?sort=l2h">Price:--low to high</a></li>
<li class="filters"><a class="filter_by" href="?sort=h2l">Price:-- high to low</a></li>
```

In your view

```
def get(self, request, subcategory_id):
        subcategory = get_object_or_404(Subcategories, pk=subcategory_id)

        sort_by = request.GET.get("sort", "l2h") 
        if sort_by == "l2h":
           products = subcategory.products.order_by("price")
        elif sort_by == "h2l":
           products = subcategory.products.order_by("-price")

        category_list = Categories.objects.all()
        return render (request, 'products.html',{"subcategory_list" : products, 'category_list': category_list })
```

Explanation :

When you click on the sorting link from frontend, just look out at your url in browser.
We are sending a `sort` parameter which tells how should we sort it.

We retrieve that parameter in our view

```
sort_by = request.GET.get("sort", "l2h")
```

Note : Here if no parameter is provided ( When user visits that page ) it will be sorted by `l2h` aka `low to high`

You can change that accordingly, what default sorting/filtering you want

Finally, we are just using django query to filter out our data.

And use that in your template

Comment: Answer for your first query : use a field `created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True`. This will store the datetime of object creation, now you can simply sort is using `order_by` query.